# Automatically mount drive on plug using systemd

Tags: mount, systemd, automount

I want to mount a drive with a specific label automatically everytime it gets pugged-in. I do *not* want to use any other tool than `systemd` as other units depend on the mount and must be started automatically.

What I have got so far:

**`/lib/systemd/system/mount-camera.mount`**

```
[Unit]
Description=the camera SDCard
StopWhenUnneeded=true
Before=copy-camera.service

[Mount]
What=LABEL=CAMERA
Where=/mount/camera
Type=vfat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**`/lib/systemd/system/mount-camera.automount`**

```
[Unit]
Description=camera SDCard

[Automount]
Where=/mount/camera

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This does successfully mount the drive if I `cd` into the mountpoint. However I want the drive to be mounted just because I insert it because there is a service that is started by the mount unit.

Is it possible to achieve this using systemd?
If yes: How?

If it is impossible: is there a way I could do it with very few  extra steps?

**Note**

I know that I could add a timer that `cd`s into the mountpoint every x seconds - but this is note really elegant, is it?

Comment: `udev` does the mounting and `systemd` monitors `udev` automatically I think.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix So there is no way to do it without writing an `udev` rule?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just add the device to the fstab?  I have a removable drive bay that I pop drives in and out all the time and they automount based on what is in fstab.

Comment: @rtaft I thought this would be in conflict with my systemd `mount` unit. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkStosberg pointed out: it appears that this is not possible with `systemd` alone.

As @rtaft pointed out: using `fstab` is worth a try.

The solution is: Add an entry to the `fstab` and you are good to go. There are no conflicts, `systemd` resolves the files automatically.

Add to `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=CAMERA                    /mount/camera auto user,rw,nofail 0 0
```

The service gets started as expected. I have kept both the `.automount` and the `.mount` unit files.

Comment: Does it mean you have the two systemd units mentioned in your question _plus_ this fstab entry? Or do you now omit one or both of the systemd units?

Comment: Btw, I have a line `LABEL=chunkA /mnt/chunkA ext4 noauto,x-systemd.automount,defaults 0 2` in my fstab (note the `x-systemd.automount` setting) and no systemd units at all to achieve automounting. But that's not a removable disk and I just did it for fun and out of curiousity.

Comment: @PerlDuck I made an edit regarding your first question. Also I need the systemd units because I automatically start another systemd service after mounting the drive.

Answer (score 2):

From reading `man systemd.mount` and `man systemd.automount`, it appears what you want is not possible `systemd` alone. [Adding udev rules is the recommended solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd).